# how to fix or change a mp4 video timestamps (frame rate) based on available frames?

Tags: avconv

I have a video file that was created as x264, 26 fps, 20MB.

command used to convert `avconv -i infile.mp4 -c:v libx265 -c:a libmp3lame outfile.mp4`

After converting it to x265 HEVC it gets wrong timestamps and so frame rate 1 fps, it has 1MB and the frames looks ok, just the time is messed.

sample warning messages:

```
mp4 @ 0x10e8660] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; 
previous: 114400515, current: 454496; changing to 114400516. 
This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

Past duration 0.644524 too large
```

the x264 file reports 23s duration, the new one x265 is 11 minutes 46 seconds...

this wont fix it: `avconv -i infile.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -r 26 outfile.mp4`

Obs.: the mp4 was created using "DU Recorder" on android, capturing the screen.